# Having Matrix Style alignment in tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode, alignment

I need to create the following table in LaTeX:

[image: The to be typeset table]

The aligning of the equations in the cells are giving me alot of trouble, the single `\moment_{ij}^0` at the end of the equation should be aligned for better reading. While prettifying the table by changing the layout a bit.

I thought it would be more fitting to align the middle equations with the pictures to the left of them, and putting `booktabs` bars to better distiguish between the many equations. I tried aligning with `phantoms`, manually doing it but nothing I did created acceptable results.

Here a MWE where I left the Equation signs left aligned, while everything squishes.

```
\documentclass[DIV=16,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\stabkenn}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\bezugsstabzahl}{\eta_s}
\newcommand{\laengskraft}{S}
\newcommand{\laenge}{\mathbf{l}}
\newcommand{\emodul}{E}
\newcommand{\ftm}{I}
\newcommand{\EI}{\emodul\ftm}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert #1\rvert}
\newcommand{\moment}{M}
\newcommand{\steifigzahl}{\kappa}
\newcommand{\fortleit}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\knotenwink}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\stabsehnen}{\psi}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
      \toprule
       & Druckbereich & \multirow{2}{*}{Theorie $\mathrm{I}$ Ordnung bzw. $S = 0$} & Zugbereich \\
       & $\laengskraft_s < 0, \, \stabkenn = \sqrt{\frac{\abs{\laengskraft_s} \laenge^2_s}{\EI_s}}$ & & $\laengskraft_s > 0, \, \stabkenn = \sqrt{\frac{\laengskraft_s \laenge^2_s}{\EI_s}}$ \\
       \midrule
       & RB & RB & RB \\
       \midrule
       \tikz{\draw[thick] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (3.0em,2.0ex);} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$\displaystyle \moment_{ij} = \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}\bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^e \left(\knotenwink_i + \fortleit_s \knotenwink_j - \left(1 + \fortleit_s \right) \stabsehnen_s \right) + \moment_{ij}^0 $} \\
       \tikz{\draw[thick] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (3.0em,2.0ex);} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$\displaystyle \moment_{ij} = \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}\bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^g \left(\knotenwink_i - \stabsehnen_s \right) + \moment_{ij}^0 $} \\
       \tikz{\draw[thick] (0.0,0.0) rectangle (3.0em,2.0ex);} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$\displaystyle \moment_{ij} = \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}\bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^k \knotenwink_i + \moment_{ij}^0 $} \\
       \midrule

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Stabendmomente, Steifigkeits- und Fortleitungszahlen}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

There are many more tables like these I need to typeset, so a more general solution would be nice to have.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How are the macros `\mathbold` and `\RNum` defined?

Comment: Please make your example compilable.

Comment: You might add  [baseline={current bounding box.center)] to your tikz pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most effective, yet also least obtrusive/disruptive, vertical alignment of the additive `\moment_{ij}^0` term may be achieved simply by listing it *first* instead of last on the right-hand side of each of the three equations in question.

E.g., instead of

```
\moment_{ij} = \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}
  \bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^e 
  \left(\knotenwink_i + \fortleit_s \knotenwink_j 
      -\left(1 + \fortleit_s \right) \stabsehnen_s \right) 
  +\moment_{ij}^0
```

how about

```
\moment_{ij} = \moment_{ij}^0
  + \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}
  \bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^e 
  \left(\knotenwink_i + \fortleit_s \knotenwink_j 
      -\left(1 + \fortleit_s \right) \stabsehnen_s \right)
```

Likewise, do consider replacing

```
\moment_{ij} = \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}
    \bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^k \knotenwink_i 
    + \moment_{ij}^0
```

with

```
\moment_{ij} = \moment_{ij}^0
    + \frac{\EI_s}{\laenge_s}
    \bezugsstabzahl \steifigzahl_s^k \knotenwink_i
```